# Issue with LoadContent converting XNA 2.0 to 4.0

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

Hello I am doing this project in school and I ran into a problem when I got a pdf with instructions to make a small and simple game. There was all the code in the pdf but the problem is that my teacher wrote the code in XNA 2.0 and we are using XNA 4.0.

The thing is that in my `LoadContent` part of the Game1.cs there is a bit of code that dont work.

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    foreach (GameObject g in gameObjects)
    {
        g.LoadContent();
    }
    // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
}
```

The part of the code that fails is the `g`. When I try to Debug it shows this error message

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in First XNA.exe
>   Additional information: Objektreferensen har inte angetts till en instans av ett objekt.

I have no idea how to fix it. If you need more info please say it so I will try to provide it.

Comment: You have to provide more information and code before we can really help you. Read the documentation and examples of XNA 4.0 I'm sure this is not difficult to solve.

Comment: You would need to post more of your code to determine the problem, although it may be that you are trying to access the gameObjects collection before initializing it.

Comment: Your list of GameObjects contains null elements, so you forgot to instance them. If you can add more code we'll can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception states : **"NullReferenceError"** means that g is null when you try to invoke LoadContent(). I have a feeling that you need to check gameObjects for consistency. 
Hope this helps!